# ODBC Connection to FoxPro Error

Tags: iis, odbc, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying to create an ODBC connection to a FoxPro database on a network drive. I have a test program to check the connection and print the contents of the database, running IIS.

Here are the three scenarios I've used this program to test:

1. ODBC connection to a MySQL database. Test program worked successfully.
2. ODBC connection to a copy of the FoxPro database I placed in the wwwroot folder. Test program worked successfully.
3. ODBC connection to the same FoxPro database on the network drive (Z:).

Option 3 gives me the following error message: "Cannot open file data.dbc".

This leads me to believe the issue is with my permissions, but I'm not sure which permissions are missing. Any clarification would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. ODBC driver would only work for versions up to 6. You should use VFPOLEDB driver instead.
2. What is identity trying to connect to z: drive? Did you impersonate someone who has right to read  & write there? For what is worth, with a web application do not try to access files on another computer.

Comment: I'll provide some more information. The shared drive is the database for another program that is being updated daily. I'm trying to pull the information from that program/database and display it in my program? The two cannot operate from the same server. Is ODBC not the way to go for this scenario?

Comment: As I said, ODBC is only good for up to version 6 databases. Later versions do not have an ODBC driver from MS. If you don't keep them on the same server I don't think you can do that (I couldn't in the past because of timeouts).

Comment: Try using a UNC path rather than a mapped drive. It being 2017 and all.

Comment: A UNC path wouldn't make a difference as long as it is on another server. It is unlikely they would want to give access to internet guest account from another server anyway.

Comment: @AlanB I have tried using a UNC path before, it didn't make a difference for this situation.

Comment: Would drive replication be a better option for this? That was another option I considered.